# Can't save info to mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, connection-string

I'm trying to store info to a mysql database, but for some reason it's not working for me.

```
Dim connString As String = "server=sql3.freemysqlhosting.net; userid=Censored;password=Censored;database=sql364455"
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
Try
    conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO accounts (`user_num`, `username`, `password`) values (@1,@2,@3)"
    MsgBox("1")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", TextBox2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", TextBox3.Text)
    MsgBox("2")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("3")
    MessageBox.Show("User Profile Created!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

According to this code the message boxes 1 and 2 is popping up but 3 is not.

Any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you add a breakpoint on the exception and see what it says?

Comment: I'm sry but can you explain how to do this?

Comment: you dont need backticks on column names, but password is a reserved word and will need to be escaped: `[password]`

Comment: also, `MsgBox` is a terrible debugging tool

Comment: I changed the line to: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO accounts (user_num, username, password) values (@1,@2,@3)"
but it's still not working.
btw, thanks for the advices.

Comment: @WoeIsMe Plutonix already told you how to write it correctly (put it into brackets: `[password]`). And, just and advice; if you're already using `MsgBox` as a debugging tool, always put another one inside the `catch` block with the exception `MsgBox(ex.ToString())`, so you'll know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @WoeIsMe Plutonix already told you how to write it correctly (put it into brackets: [password]). And, just and advice; if you're already using MsgBox as a debugging tool, always **put another one inside the catch block with the exception MsgBox(ex.ToString()), so you'll know why it is not working.** –  Josh Part 8

I've put a msgbox on the exception block to find out what is the problem and I found that it didn't worked because: "Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' " - it didn't worked because there was already a user with this number.

thanks alot for all the people who helped me.

the code I used to detect the problem:

```
    Dim connString As String = "server=sql3.freemysqlhosting.net; userid=username;password=password;database=sql364455"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connString)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO accounts (user_num, username, password) values (@1,@2,@3)"
        MsgBox("1")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", TextBox2.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", TextBox3.Text)
        MsgBox("2")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("3")
        MessageBox.Show("User Profile Created!", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' here
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```